# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with IONIC 2 and Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic2

My component code is, I'm calling a third part jquery library here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
declare var jQuery:any; 
import '../../assets/js/d3.v3.js'; 
declare var d3: any; 
import '../../assets/js/zackscharts.js'; 
declare var PriceChart: any;


    @Component({   selector: 'page-zacks-chart',  templateUrl: 'zacks-chart.html' })

export class ZacksChartPage {

    title : string;
    description : string;
    ticker : string;
    upperName : string;
    chartData = {};

constructor()
  {
    this.title = 'Zacks Chart';
    this.description = 'Zacks Chart Table';    
  }

ngOnInit()
 {  
     this.init_charts( 'chart_form', 'chart_canvas' );     
 }

init_charts( form_id, chart_id )
{
// call an API to fetch data
}
}
```

but when I'm running this app on browser its returning error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Dataset.PriceChart.Dataset.Dataset.find (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:109239:23)
    at Dataset.PriceChart.Dataset.Dataset.fetch (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:109211:26)
    at PriceChart.parseData (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107846:30)
    at PriceChart.run (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107948:34)
    at Dataset.PriceChart.Dataset.Dataset.fetch (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:109212:24)
    at PriceChart.update (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107920:33)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107848:34
    at Dataset.PriceChart.Dataset.Dataset.fetch (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:109212:24)
    at PriceChart.parseData (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107846:30)
    at PriceChart.run (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:107948:34)
```

I'm very new to Angular 2 .. I'm not using any minified library. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably have circular import somewhere in your app.

Comment: I have checked it very carefully. I have only import two files at top of this component.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be in this file, check imports and exports of your modules.